# Adaptive theme css which stylesheet to use?

Tags: theming

In the adaptive theme in the sass folder and it has following files, I understand about some stylesheets and for what purpose they are. But I am confuse about `global.base.scss`, `global.style.scss`, `responsive.desktop.scss`, `responsive.custom.scss` and `print.scss`. Now which one shall I use specific purpose.

e.g. `global.base.scss` and `global.style.scss`, both has `html` and `body` now if we want to use `font-size: 62.5%` in `root` for using `rem` as `unit` so in which `html` shall I have to put?

Comment: Please don't fundamentally change the substance of a question when it's already been answered. Thanks

Comment: Hmmm...took a note, onward will make a new separate question..very thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The AdaptiveTheme site has a lot of great [documentation](http://adaptivethemes.com/documentation/css) to help explain this.

In general, you should use `global.styles.scss` to style elements that will look the same across all devices, and the individual responsive stylesheets (e.g. `responsive.desktop.scss`) for device-specific styles. If you want to override something in `global.base.scss`, you're probably best off doing it in `global.styles.scss`, depending on how fundamental the change is.

Comment: Yes it is there, even at first place I did check that entirely. they have described few facts, But do not have explicit instructions which developer needs to decide their way. Your answer helps, Thanks.